# FirebaseAuth no aparece en xCode

Tags: firebase, ios, xcode, firebase-auth

estoy haciendo una app para aprender Swift. Instale el package de Firebase y me sale unicamente estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito que me salga FirebaseAuth para poder usarlo en mi proyecto.